# Как заменить функцию класса или класс из /inc/ в дочерней теме Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

Сделал дочернюю тему, все работает хорошо, кроме одного. В родительской теме есть файл /inc/wp_bootstrap_navwalker.php с классом и функцией которые надо немного изменить (отвечает за работу меню).

```
class wp_bootstrap_navwalker extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
    public function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
...
    }
}
```

Возможно ли в дочерней теме как-либо переназначить эту функцию или класс целиком?

Comment: Вы хотите не использовать этот класс? Использовать построение меню по своему принципу? Или же по "заводскому шаблону"?

Comment: @pepel_xD Я хочу использовать построение меню по своему принципу. А именно - мне необходимо закомментировать пару строк в оригинальной функции. Возможно как-то это сделать в дочерней теме, чтобы не прибегать к изменению файла родительской?

Comment: можно полностью описать класс так как нужно, в шаблоне где выводиться меню обратиться уже к новому объекту.

Comment: @pepel_xD Да, как раз то, что надо. Благодарю за подсказку. Сделал `header.php` в который добавил этот класс под новым именем и обратился к нему - сработало. Видимо, это единственное возможное решение. Добавите ответ, отмечу его как верный?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pepel_xD подсказал верное решение:

Нужно полностью описать класс так как нужно, в шаблоне где выводиться меню обратиться уже к новому объекту.
В header.php дочерней темы добавил этот класс под новым именем и обратился уже к нему - сработало.